# How set multiples handles in jquery

Tags: jquery, handle

Have this code

```
 $( ".sortable" )
  .sortable({ handle: ".handle",
  })
  .selectable()
    .find( "li" )
      .addClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .prepend( "<div class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></div>" );
```

and need set multiples handles because have two img with function onclick and doesnt work
only work last handle writted
ex:

```
 $( ".sortable" )
  .sortable({ handle: ".handle",
handle:".play",
handle:".remove"
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({ handle: ".handle,.play,.remove"});
```

Should do the trick. I did a quick test here:

http://jsfiddle.net/x4BzU/

Comment: thanks, only need to fix quotes $( ".sortable" )
  .sortable({ handle: ".handle,.play,.remove",
  }) and work it!!